# How to record desktop and stream it in webcam ubuntu 17.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, streaming, webcam

I was able to stream desktop in virtual webcam using this command:

`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 && v4l2-ctl --list-devices && ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 20 -s 400x400 -i :0.0+50,100 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video1`

After installing all dependencies on ubuntu 17.04 the desktop streaming does not work and I see only a black screen.

Are there any alternatives that would allow me to record desktop and share it in a webcam?

I want to work with the desktop recording in webcam because of opencv.

I could not find any other working alternative.

**WebcamStudio**

Can't install this one because of 
`E: The repository 'https://content.runescape.com/downloads/ubuntu trusty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

**Open Broadcaster Software**

This one looked amazing until I found out that it cannot stream the desktop into a webcam for some reason...

Comment: What are you using to view the output from ffmpeg? The console output from ffmpeg would be informative.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind a GUI, [VLC VideoLAN](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-linux-vlc-streaming-media-server-home/) can stream video on Linux (and on Windows) platforms. If it not in the *Ubuntu Software* center, then just enter:

> sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: Can I stream the video in virtual webcam?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but VLC accepts all sources I *have* used, so far. N.B. it is deficient on error reporting, e.g. a long filename for output just fails without notice, so you may need to experiment a bit before it succeeds.

Comment: I mean I need to stream the video INTO the webcam. I want to record the desktop and then I want to send the desktop into webcam. So that I can read the webcam with opencv. Anyway I will take a look at it thanks.